# I cannot start qemu-kvm on a CentOS 6 server

Tags: qemu, libvirt

I am using qemu-kvm on a CentOS 6.6 node. For no apparent reason, this node rebooted during the night, and the virtual machines did not automatically start at boot time.

I am trying to start the machine and I get this error :

```
# start srv50
error: Failed to start domain srv50
error: internal error problem reading /sys/devices/system/node/node0: No such file or directory
```

I tried to check whether /sys/devices/system/node/node0 was accessible and it seems to be :

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Sep 12 08:22 /sys/devices/system/node/node0
```

Here is the libvirt log file :

```
2015-09-12 07:47:43.039+0000: 2933: info : libvirt version: 0.10.2, package: 54.el6 (CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>, 2015-07-24-04:48:57, c6b9.bsys.dev.centos.org)
2015-09-12 07:47:43.039+0000: 2933: info : virNetlinkEventServiceStart:517 : starting netlink event service with protocol 0
2015-09-12 07:47:43.040+0000: 2933: info : virNetlinkEventServiceStart:517 : starting netlink event service with protocol 15
2015-09-12 07:47:43.044+0000: 2945: info : dnsmasqCapsSetFromBuffer:667 : dnsmasq version is 2.48, --bind-dynamic is NOT present, SO_BINDTODEVICE is NOT in use
2015-09-12 07:47:43.045+0000: 2945: info : networkReloadIptablesRules:1980 : Reloading iptables rules
2015-09-12 07:47:43.094+0000: 2945: info : networkRefreshDaemons:1342 : Refreshing network daemons
2015-09-12 07:47:43.095+0000: 2945: info : virStorageBackendVolOpenCheckMode:1093 : Skipping special dir '..'
2015-09-12 07:47:43.095+0000: 2945: info : virStorageBackendVolOpenCheckMode:1093 : Skipping special dir '.'
2015-09-12 07:47:43.095+0000: 2945: info : virStorageBackendVolOpenCheckMode:1093 : Skipping special dir '..'
2015-09-12 07:47:43.095+0000: 2945: info : virStorageBackendVolOpenCheckMode:1093 : Skipping special dir '.'
2015-09-12 07:47:43.223+0000: 2945: info : qemudLoadDriverConfig:443 : Configured cgroup controller 'cpu'
2015-09-12 07:47:43.223+0000: 2945: info : qemudLoadDriverConfig:443 : Configured cgroup controller 'cpuacct'
2015-09-12 07:47:43.223+0000: 2945: info : qemudLoadDriverConfig:443 : Configured cgroup controller 'cpuset'
2015-09-12 07:47:43.223+0000: 2945: info : qemudLoadDriverConfig:443 : Configured cgroup controller 'memory'
2015-09-12 07:47:43.223+0000: 2945: info : qemudLoadDriverConfig:443 : Configured cgroup controller 'devices'
2015-09-12 07:47:43.223+0000: 2945: info : qemudLoadDriverConfig:443 : Configured cgroup controller 'blkio'
2015-09-12 07:47:43.225+0000: 2945: error : virNodeParseNode:263 : problem reading /sys/devices/system/node/node0: No such file or directory
2015-09-12 07:47:43.225+0000: 2945: warning : qemuCapsInit:880 : Failed to get host CPU
2015-09-12 07:47:43.347+0000: 2945: info : virDomainLoadAllConfigs:15374 : Scanning for configs in /var/run/libvirt/qemu
2015-09-12 07:47:43.354+0000: 2945: info : virDomainLoadAllConfigs:15374 : Scanning for configs in /etc/libvirt/qemu
2015-09-12 07:47:43.354+0000: 2945: info : virDomainLoadAllConfigs:15396 : Loading config file 'srv50.xml'
2015-09-12 07:47:43.355+0000: 2945: info : virDomainLoadAllConfigs:15396 : Loading config file 'srv51.xml'
2015-09-12 07:47:43.355+0000: 2945: info : qemuDomainSnapshotLoad:494 : Scanning for snapshots for domain srv51 in /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/snapshot/srv51
2015-09-12 07:47:43.355+0000: 2945: info : qemuDomainSnapshotLoad:494 : Scanning for snapshots for domain srv50 in /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/snapshot/srv50
2015-09-12 07:47:43.378+0000: 2945: info : lxcSecurityInit:1380 : lxcSecurityInit (null)
2015-09-12 07:47:43.378+0000: 2945: info : virDomainLoadAllConfigs:15374 : Scanning for configs in /var/run/libvirt/lxc
2015-09-12 07:47:43.378+0000: 2945: info : virDomainLoadAllConfigs:15374 : Scanning for configs in /etc/libvirt/lxc
```

I tried to upgrade CentOS to the latest version, as this reset libvirtd configuration, but I still get the same errors.

How can I start those virtual machines and what's wrong with the node files ?

Answer (score 1):

Your server may be compromised, according to some similiar cases recently.

You should check your `/etc/rc.local` to see if anything added like `_-pud` and `_-minerd`. If they are exist then you are one of the victims.

To get your VMs back, you need to remove those files:

- `/usr/bin/_-minerd`
- `/usr/bin/_-pud`
- `/usr/bin/_-config`
- `/etc/ld.so.preload`
- `/lib64/libncom.so.4.0.1`
- `/tmp/initramfs.*/lib64/libncom.so.4.0.1`

And don't forget to remove those two lines in `/etc/rc.local`:

- `nohup /usr/bin/_-pud 119.78.232.8 >/dev/null`
- `nohup /usr/bin/_-minerd -c /usr/bin/_-config 2> /dev/null&`

VMs should be up and running at your next reboot.

Please remember to check if your IPMI or iDRAC is accessible from the Internet, this issue is caused by vulnerabilities in the IPMI firmware. Update to a new version of firmware is recommended.

References:

- http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?p=9534226
- http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1512831